# Add id attribute to previous next links

Tags: php, wordpress

I wonder how to add id attribute to links generated by `previous_posts_link()` and `next_posts_link()` 
functions. I found that I can add class with this code:

```
add_filter('next_posts_link_attributes', 'posts_link_attributes');
add_filter('previous_posts_link_attributes', 'posts_link_attributes');

function posts_link_attributes() {
    return 'class="styled-button"';
}
```

But how to to do with `id` attribute ?

Comment: Are you expecting a particular ID for each link? If so, what values do you want to use?

Comment: I just want <a href="" id="prev"></a> <a href="" id="next>

Comment: What do you want to do with the `id`? Just add special styles?

Comment: ...Like what, add some tracking cookie?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you could simply use multiple filters to handle this:

```
add_filter('next_posts_link_attributes', 'set_next_id');
add_filter('previous_posts_link_attributes', 'set_previous_id');

function set_next_id() {
    return 'id="next"';
}

function set_previous_id() {
    return 'id="previous"';
}
```